# Proof that $\text{Ext}(\text{Ext}(\Omega))$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, i want to show that $\text{Ext}(\text{Ext}(\Omega))$ is open, but in my case i say that a set $\Omega$ is open if:

$\Omega=\text{Int}(\Omega)$, and $p$ is interior point of $\Omega$ if $\exists C_{n} \ni p$ with $C_{n} \subseteq \Omega$ from where

$$I_{1} \times \cdots \times I_{n}$$, with $I_{i}$ is a open set of $\mathbb{R}$.

For this rectangles, it seems that the proposition is not true, since we can take

$\text{Int}(\mathbb{Q})= \emptyset$ and $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$ but

$$\text{Ext}(\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Q}))=\mathbb{R}$$

Is the latter at all true, is the proposition true, and if so, I have my doubts about the return contention.

Comment: $\text{Ext}$ of any set is always open (because it is defined as the interior of the complement).

Comment: You need to provide the definition of $\rm Ext$. Also, note that $\Bbb R$ is open, so, your example is not a counterexample.